# .net core 6 - Entity Framework - when to use AsEnumerable AsQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

**Background**

I've migrated my project from .net core 2.2 to .net core 6 few weeks ago. Over the past weeks I am seeing issues with `Entity Framework` calls that worked well in the past.

**The Issue**

The following code used to work well on .net core 2.2:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
        return await context.Accounts
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(account => SOME_CONDITIONS)
                    .ToArrayAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

We have found out that now this code is getting stuck in some kind of a deadlock, function does not return.

**Suggested Solution**

Adding `AsAsyncEnumerable` fixes the issues and the function finish executing very fast:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
        return await context.Accounts
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .AsAsyncEnumerable()
                    .Where(account => SOME_CONDITIONS)
                    .ToArrayAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**The Question**

I saw that it is recommended to use AsEnumerable/AsAsyncEnumerable/AsQueryable for calls using EF on .net core 6.

When should I use `AsEnumerable`/`AsAsyncEnumerable`/`AsQueryable`?

Comment: Could you please reduce the post to a single question? I will be hard to write an answer to solve all questions at once

Comment: @TheTanic I will try

Answer (score 5):

The typical error you will see when moving from EF Core 2.x to 3.x+ around queries working then not working has to do with a feature in EF Core called client-side evaluation. What this essentially did was set it so that when EF encountered something it couldn't compose down to SQL (typically in the `Where` clause, but also could be in the `Select`) it would execute a query using what it could compose down to SQL at that point, and then re-run the rest against the entities in memory.

With EF Core 2.x this feature was enabled by default. In EF Core 3+ it was disabled by default. The danger of client side evaluation is similar to lazy loading, it is a fail-safe to help ensure your code ultimately executes, but it can hide potentially devastating performance issues, especially in cases with new systems that are developed without a real sense of production data loads. Nice and fast when you only have a few hundred test records, but blows up as production sets span millions of rows that the server is trying to load into memory.

So in your case the typical culprit will be something in your `Where` clause conditions. This is usually something like calling a method on an entity or using a C# function that EF cannot ultimately translate down to SQL.

Using `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` prior to the `Where` clause will essentially perform the client-side evaluation by loading the query into entities in memory befor attempting the `Where` clause.  Obviously the cost here is you are loading ***all*** entities into memory.  Alternatively you can opt to enable client-side evaluation and get roughly the same behaviour.

The best solution is to always seek to avoid anything that cannot evaluate down to SQL.

Other solutions to consider:

Move all `Where` conditions that can translate to SQL into a `Where` prior to the `AsEnumerable`. This will help ensure that the minimum amount of data is loaded for client-side evaluation.

For example if I had something like:

```
return await context.Accounts
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(a => a.CreatedAt >= startDate && a.CreatedAt < endDate && someEvaluation(a))
    .ToArrayAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

That `someEvaluation` method wouldn't be able to be composed down to SQL so it would require client-side evaluation. Using an `AsEnumerable` method prior to the Where clause would involve loading **all** accounts into memory. Instead, I could do this:

```
return await context.Accounts
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(a => a.CreatedAt >= startDate && a.CreatedAt < endDate)
    .AsEnumerableAsync()
    .Where(a => someEvaluation(a))
    .ToArrayAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

At least in this case the accounts that would be loaded into memory would be limited to the date range.

For complex conditional expressions it might not be that simple. Wherever possible you should strive to keep expressions pure to entity properties and computations that can ultimately boil down to SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Regarding to AsQueryable, does it have the same effect or does it operates differently?

Comment: When working with EF Linq queries, the object will already be returned as an `IQueryable` or `IOrderedQueryable`. `AsQueryable` is typically only needed if you want to conditionally compose your query, such as only adding a Where clause if a variable isn't null so C# is happy it's working with the DbSet as an `IQueryable`. `var query = context.Accounts.AsQueryable(); if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter)) query = query.Where(x => x.AccountName.StartsWith(nameFilter)); ` That sort of thing. `AsQueryable` will not execute the query to memory where `AsEnumerable` / `ToList` will.